# How to find match letter in (mystring after match letter)

Tags: c#, regex

I have need to check complex property in c#. I get the complex property List of string are:

```
   EmployeeID
   contactNo
   Employee.FirstName  // these is complex property
   Employee.LastName   //  these is complex property
```

I know about regex.match() but i have doubt about how to check the string in after placed in dot value that means i want to check in Employee and after placed dot value. can you please help any idea about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex, you can match complex properties like this:

```
List<string> properties = new List<string>()
{
    "EmployeeID",
    "contactNo",
    "Employee.FirstName",  // these is complex property
    "Employee.LastName",   //  these is complex property
};

Regex rgx = new Regex(@"Employee\.(.*)");

var results = new List<string>();
foreach(var prop in properties)
{
    foreach (var match in rgx.Matches(prop))
    {
        results.Add(match.ToString());
    }
}
```

If you just want what is after the `.` (`FirstName` and `LastName`), replace the pattern like this:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=Employee\.)\w*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex:

```
List<string> listofstring = { .... };
List<string> results = new List<string>();
const string toMatch = "Employee.";
foreach (string str in listofstring)
{
   if (str.StartsWith(toMatch))
   {
      results.Add(str.Substring(toMatch.Length));
   }
}
```

If you just need to match `.`

```
List<string> listofstring = { .... };
List<string> results = new List<string>();
const string toMatch = ".";
int index = -1;
foreach (string str in listofstring)
{
   index = str.IndexOf(toMatch);
   if(index >= 0)
   { 
      results.Add(str.Substring(index + 1));
   }
}
```